# How to reduce XNA game CPU usage while nothing worth computing is happening?

Tags: performance, xna

A fresh XNA game project application consumes quite some CPU percentage while its window is active. On my desktop PC it's about 30% of one core of a 2-core processor. When the window loses focus, the game goes into idle mode and consumes about 1% of CPU.

In an image viewer application I recently made using XNA, redrawing frames when no image manipulation is going on doesn't make much sense, so I'm using the `SuppressDraw()` method which, as the name suggests, suppresses spending resources for drawing the next frame, showing the last drawn frame instead. But still, there's a problem where the application keeps wasting CPU for a very simple input update.

How do I reduce the CPU usage for an XNA application when it doesn't require much of it?

Comment: profile your application to see where it is spending its processing time. Then change the execution flow to avoid unnecessary processing.

Comment: @axon as I said, the input update is very simple. The application doesn't consume a lot when its window is not in focus, but when it is, it's way too high for doing nothing.

Comment: You could simply add Sleep(100) to the main loop. No point rendering 100s of frames per second if there's no benefit. Alternatively, have a target frame rate and adjust your sleep time to hit that target.

Comment: @axon I really don't think this is an option for a PC XNA application.

Comment: It is. You really should try it. "If you actually need to wait a specific amount of time for something, then sleep is appropriate." From: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1096794/is-sleep-evil  Of course, if you are using a framework that has this already implemented, then use it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

quote from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8553998/high-cpu-usage-with-xna) question

> According to this discussion on XBox Live Indie Games forum , apparently on some processors (and OS-s) XNA takes up 100% CPU time on one core when the default value of Game.IsFixedTimeStep is used.
>
> A common solution (one that worked for me as well) is to put the following in your Game constructor:
> `IsFixedTimeStep = false;`

more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8554106/1821428)