# Scrolling lag during draw

Tags: xna, 2d, monogame

I have started working on a new game using xna/monogame. I have designed a few 2D games before but decided to make this one isometric which is new to me. I have been using reimers isometric tile engine tutorial and most of the drawing code at its simplest level is a copy of this.

When scrolling around the map there is a stuttering on the screen which I can only describe as lag. I have put an FPS counter on and this stays at a solid 60 so I believe this is some kind of graphics problem.

I have tried commenting out sections of the drawing code to narrow down the issue but cant seem to make any progress, however this wasnt happening a couple of weeks ago so I'm confident its something that I have added, perhaps an issue with on the of the tilesets that's causing it?

Any suggestions are appreciated. I haven't put any code here as its turned into quite a large project and I don't know which area to concentrate on but I have uploaded the whole project [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=47297466069786342879) if anybody is kind enough to investigate.

Comment: Micky, What part would be useful? I tested a bit further last night and it seems to be worse when the game first starts and almost stop after scrolling around for a bit, almost as if its loading the textures the first time you see them and works fine after that point.

Comment: Stuttering in .NET games can be caused by the GC kicking in.  Check out the tips by Shawn Hargreaves  and Riemer in their respective XNA blogs.  As for start-up lag, do you do any form of load-on-demand asset stuff?

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look into that. No load-on-demand that I've put in, was wondering if XNA does any itself but I'm fairly sure this isn't the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tl;dr You are creating a new `Texture2D` instance (1x1 pixel) called `dummyTexture` on **each call** to the `DrawMiniMap` method. This is a bad idea, as textures need to be sent to the GPU every time (and then disposed, and collected). Add a field named `dummyTexture` and fully initialize it inside `LoadContent`.

But please read the rest of the post to see how to identify these issues.

Your `Update` method is being called at 60fps, but this doesn't have to be true for the `Draw` method too. Since `Game.IsFixedTimeStep` is set to `true` by default, as soon as Monogame sees that `Draw` is taking longer than expected to finish, your `Draw` method will skip frames.

Due to the way your game logic is written right now, this is the only way for Monogame to ensure that all **updates are done in fixed time steps**.

To get better insight into what's happening, first create an additional set of fps variables for `Draw` method fps, and render both values on the screen. You will see that `Update` is drawn at 60 fps, but `Draw` falls below that.

```
protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
    // similar to what you have inside `Update`
    drawFpsTimer += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime;
    drawFpsCount++;
    if (drawFpsTimer >= TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
    { drawFpsTimer = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0); drawFps = drawFpsCount; drawFpsCount = 0; }

    ...
```

With this in place it's easy to pinpoint the problematic method inside `Draw`, and get your fps back to 60.

Also, by setting `IsFixedTimeStep` to `false` you can get both `Update` and `Draw` to be called in succession, but your `Update` frame rate will drop too - meaning you should change all your update logic to use `gameTime.ElapsedGameTime` instead of presuming fixed steps:

```
protected override void Initialize()
{
    // use variable time step
    this.IsFixedTimeStep = false;
    this.TargetElapsedTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1 / 60.0);
    this.graphics.SynchronizeWithVerticalRetrace = true;

    ...
```

I prefer variable time step in all my projects, especially when you find out that [XNA sometimes takes up 100% CPU time on one core when the default value of `Game.IsFixedTimeStep` is used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8553998/69809), but get ready for some refactoring then.

As for *why* the frames are being skipped, it seems it's the `DrawMiniMap` method that's problematic. Commenting this out gives 60 fps update + 60 fps draw rate on my machine.

Upon further inspection, it turns out you are creating a new `Texture2D` instance (1x1 pixel) called `dummyTexture` on **each call to this method**. This is a bad idea. Add a field named `dummyTexture` and fully initialize it inside `LoadContent`. You could also slightly speed up this method by making `tileColour` a member of the `Tile` class to avoid a bunch of `if` tests on each iteration, but there are probably many optimizations like this and are perhaps not needed unless you are deploying to mobile devices.

Comment: Thanks for all the info, very helpful and I will take a look into this. I would note that the minimap code was a new addition and I had the problem before that point. Completely forgot to move the dummy texture though, thanks for the reminder! :p

Comment: Really nice reading, not everyone would go that far as to download files from websites marked as suspicious and debug/read all but the relevant files to write a detailed answer.

Comment: @user3218507: well, this is what I see on my machine. The game *is* already strangely cpu heavy for such a seemingly simple game; e.g. if I disable vsync and comment out everything except the `DrawCursor` part (which is where you draw fps), frame rate goes to ~400fps, as expected. But, with and everything being drawn, frame rate is somewhere near 80fps (vsync disabled), which means you don't have much room left. So I would recommend you use a profiler and try to find all other bottlenecks.

Comment: I have a few ideas what could be causing that. I've been led astray thinking I had a constant 60 fps haha. Thanks for all the help, hopefully I can sort it out now

Comment: @user3218507: if you're using VS2015 community, you have a profiler with it, so use it to avoid optimizing at the wrong places. Also, now that I took a better look at `DrawMiniMap`, it's definitely problematic as it makes a huge number of draws for each pixel on the map. On my machine, it's responsible for pretty much all the CPU spent inside `Draw`. You should rewrite it to draw to an offscreen buffer and update the texture with this data (never create new instances inside `Draw` or `Update`).

Comment: I have sorted the lag problem out now and made some of the changes you mentioned. You have been a massive help!. One small thing, I used your fps code in the draw method but it still sticks at 60, same as the update fps and never goes any higher....

Comment: @user3218507: if you've set `this.IsFixedTimeStep` to `false`, then they will both show the same value, even if fps drops below 60. If you left it at default value of `true`, then adding a `Thread.Sleep(5)` inside `Draw` should show the difference (i.e. fps should drop). However, it will never go higher because vsync is on (`SynchronizeWithVerticalRetrace` is `true`), meaning that `Draw` calls are synchronized with your monitor refresh rate (and `TargetElapsedTime` is most likely set to `1 / 60.0`, also).

Comment: To get the maximum rate, set `SynchronizeWithVerticalRetrace` to `false` (this is what game reviewers do when doing benchmarks, although it will introduce screen tearing at higher-than-vsync framerates). This will give you an idea of how fast these methods can go while testing (I usually have a "maxfps" setting for this purpose). Since you don't seem to have any shaders running, I'd say your game is rather CPU-bound (as expected from a "civilization" game), so (when the time comes and if your fps are inadequate) you'll need to go profile your code to try to reduce loops/allocations and stuff.

Comment: Ah I follow now, a lot of great advice. Thanks for all the help, really appreciated.